# Obtain value from same column twice with different condition in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hii I want to Obtain value from same column twice with different condition in single query

Here is my code

```
SELECT
    o.products_options_name,
    ov.products_options_values_name AS products_options_values_name,
    a.options_values_quantity  
FROM
    table_products_options o,
    table_products_attributes a
WHERE
    a.options_id = o.products_options_id
    AND 
    o.products_options_values_id = a.options_values_id 
    AND
    a.products_id = :products_id 
    AND
    a.options2_values_id = options2_values_id
```

i want to obtain value of column products_options_values_name again with different condition like where a.options2_values_id = ov.products_options_values_id in same query. How can i do this?

Comment: where is alias 'ov' ?

Answer (score 0):

try by using UNION operator,

```
SELECT o.products_options_name, ov.products_options_values_name AS products_options_values_name,
a.options_values_quantity  
FROM 
table_products_options o, table_products_attributes a
WHERE 
a.options_id = o.products_options_id AND ov.products_options_values_id = a.options_values_id 
AND a.products_id = :products_id1 AND 
a.options2_values_id = options2_values_id 

UNION 

SELECT o.products_options_name, ov.products_options_values_name AS products_options_values_name,
 a.options_values_quantity  
FROM 
table_products_options o, table_products_attributes a
WHERE 
a.options_id = o.products_options_id AND ov.products_options_values_id = a.options_values_id
AND a.products_id = :products_id2 AND 
a.options2_values_id = options2_values_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Union / Union all would be best

like

```
select o.products_options_name, ov.products_options_values_name as     
products_options_values_name, a.options_values_quantity  
from 
table_products_options o, table_products_attributes a
where 
a.options_id = o.products_options_id and ov.products_options_values_id =     
a.options_values_id and a.products_id = :products_id and  a.options2_values_id = 
options2_values_id 

UNION 

select o.products_options_name, ov.products_options_values_name as products_options_values_name, a.options_values_quantity  
from 
table_products_options o, table_products_attributes a
where Diffrent Clause
```

Union Works like Distinct, Union ALL will return duplicate values if your clauses both return the value.

Alternatively use OR in your where clause `and (a.b = c.d OR c.d=b.a) and`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the condition that you want in the `on` clause.  `on` clause?  Your query should use explicit `join` syntax.

Here is one way to express the query that you want:

```
select o.products_options_name, ov.products_options_values_name as products_options_values_name, 
       a.options_values_quantity  
from table_products_options o join
     table_products_attributes a
     on a.options_id = o.products_options_id and
        (ov.products_options_values_id = a.options_values_id or
         a.options2_values_id = options2_values_id
        )
where a.products_id = :products_id;
```